# querySelector incorrectly returning null on specific website

Tags: javascript, dom, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, selectors-api

I've been trying to add a new button to the homepage of SoundCloud.com with GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey and I'm having no luck. My querySelector keeps returning null when I try to get a list.

Here is the HTML extract (from https://soundcloud.com/stream):

```
<div class="streamExploreTabs">
  <ul class="g-tabs g-tabs-large streamExploreTabs__streamTab">
    <li class="g-tabs-item">
      <a class="g-tabs-link active" href="/stream">Stream</a>
    </li>
    <li class="g-tabs-item">
      <a class="g-tabs-link " href="/charts/top">Charts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And my Javascript is:

```
var streamExploreTabsList = document.querySelector("div.streamExploreTabs ul");
var DanceEDMButton = document.createElement("li");
var DanceEDMButtonText = document.createTextNode("Dance/EDM");
DanceEDMButton.appendChild(DanceEDMButtonText);
streamExploreTabsList.appendChild(DanceEDMButton);
```

The issue is that the querySelector appears to be returning `null`. I have [replicated this in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jazymha/#&togetherjs=QkbsGywAw1) and it works fine.

I've tried getting a few different nodes and they all seem to fail.

Has anybody come across this before? Could there be something on the page itself that is preventing this Javascript from running successfully?
I've hit a real sticking point here so I'd appreciate any comments.

Comment: Soundcloud probably inserts those elements with javascript at a later time

Comment: I haven't used their API, but my best bet is that they must have a callback method to allow you to handle those elements once they have been loaded. You are probably running this JS code before that happens

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I put my code within a setTimeout() with a delay of 500 milliseconds and it works! I can live with a small delay.

Comment: You should post this as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, actually a fixed-interval timeout is going to intermittently/eventually fail and/or needlessly delay things if the delay is excessive.  OP should use mutation observers or `waitForKeyElements()`-like utility.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Well, the great thing about posting a self-answer as an answer is that it can not only be upvoted... it can also be downvoted.